# Multiple Inner Join during update operation

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, inner-join

Is it possible to do a double Inner Join during the update operation in Access?

The following code doesnt' works for me:

```
UPDATE [TableA]

INNER JOIN [TableB] ON [TableB].Field1=  [TableA].Field1,
INNER JOIN [TableC] ON [TableC].Field2 = [TableB].Field2

Set 
[TableA].Field3 = 'Test'

where [TableC].Field4 = 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

For `SQL SERVER`:

```
UPDATE A
Set 
A.Field3 = 'Test'
FROM [TableA] A
INNER JOIN [TableB] B ON B.Field1 = A.Field1
INNER JOIN [TableC] C ON C.Field2 = B.Field2
where C.Field4 = 0
```

For `MS ACCESS`

```
UPDATE ([TableA]
INNER JOIN [TableB] ON [TableB].Field1 = [TableA].Field1)
INNER JOIN [TableC] ON [TableC].Field2 = [TableB].Field2
Set [TableA].Field3 = 'Test'
where [TableC].Field4 = 0
```

Comment: It doesnt' works. The error says: Syntex error (missing operator) in query expression  'Test'
FROM [TableA] A
INNER JOIN [TableB] B ON B.Field1 = A.Field1,

Comment: Do you want statement for sql server or access?

Comment: @dario, try with alias, `A.Field3 = 'Test'`. I've updated answer.

Comment: For access. And with de A.Field says the same error.

Answer (score 0):

General syntax for multiple join update operation is the following:

```
UPDATE T1
[INNER JOIN | LEFT JOIN] T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1
[INNER JOIN | LEFT JOIN] T3 ON T2.C2 = T3.C2
SET T1.C2 = T2.C2
WHERE condition
```